# android call url in for loop

Tags: android, multithreading

I am calling a url inside a for:each using new Thread.start.
The data is getting uploaded, but the threads are executing in parallel.
I want to call the url in series depending on the status of the previous url. Is there any inbuilt functionality in android to call url in series.

This is my current Code:

```
for(Item i : foodList) { 
     if(i.isSection()) { 
          SectionItem item= (SectionItem) i; 
     } else { 
          Food f= (Food) i; 
          Upload(f.getFoodId(), 
               String.valueOf(f.getCalories()),
               f.getQuantity(),
               f.getUnit()
          ); 
     } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes i am using rest api.' for(Item i:foodList){
                if(i.isSection()){
                    SectionItem item= (SectionItem) i;
                }else{
                    Food f= (Food) i;
                    Upload(f.getFoodId(), String.valueOf(f.getCalories()),f.getQuantity(),f.getUnit());
                }
            }'

Answer (score 0):

You can implement queue - run next operation when current is finished, but I could suggest you several things:

1) Don't use threads for data upload directly, you will face troubles with this approach.

2) Use services for 'long' operations.

3) Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) for rest implementation in Android.